# jQuery does not work during css animation

Tags: jquery, css, animation

I am currently building a small menu consisting of two images. The image caption on these images was build with [this little CSS stylesheet.](http://www.cssscript.com/animated-image-grid-with-css3-based-hover-caption-effects-incontent/) I am using the images to switch between different `<div>` containers, filled with text.

But since I've integrated the CSS captions, the jQuery "toggle" statement won't work constantly any more. It seems like it only works when the animation has stopped. Therefore I can't switch the `<div>` containers during the CSS animation.

Additionally, the problem does not occur on Google Chrome (by now, only on Firefox).

Here is a shortened version (try to switch rapidly between the two divs, by clicking on the images):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

 $(".first-content").hide();

 $(".second-content").hide();

});

$("#first").click(function(){

 $(".home-text").hide();

    $(".second-content").hide();

 $(".first-content").fadeIn(200);

});

  

$("#second").click(function(){

 $(".home-text").hide();

 $(".first-content").hide();

    $(".second-content").fadeIn(200);

});
```

```css
@import "http://font-style: em;googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans)";html,body,div,span,applet,object,iframe,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,p,blockquote,pre,a,abbr,acronym,address,big,cite,code,del,dfn,em,img,ins,kbd,q,s,samp,small,strike,strong,sub,sup,tt,var,b,u,i,center,dl,dt,dd,ol,ul,li,fieldset,form,label,legend,table,caption,tbody,tfoot,thead,tr,th,td,article,aside,canvas,details,embed,figure,figcaption,footer,header,hgroup,menu,nav,output,ruby,section,summary,time,mark,audio,video{margin:0;padding:0;border:0;font-size:100%;font:inherit;vertical-align:baseline}article,aside,details,figcaption,figure,footer,header,hgroup,menu,nav,section{display:block}body{line-height:1}ol,ul{list-style:none}blockquote,q{quotes:none}blockquote:before,blockquote:after,q:before,q:after{content:'';content:none}table{border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0}body{background:rgba(44,62,80,0.92);color:#fff;font-size:14px;font-family:'Open Sans', sans-serif, 'trebuhet ms',HelveticaNeue, arial;height:100%;line-height:20px}*{-webkit-box-sizing:border-box;-moz-box-sizing:border-box;-o-box-sizing:border-box;-ms-box-sizing:border-box;box-sizing:border-box}p{line-height:2.0em}h1{font-size:3.0em;line-height:40px}a{text-decoration:none;color:rgba(74,92,110,0.92)}a:hover{color:#fff}img{max-width:100%}.pull-right{float:right}.pull-left{float:left}header{padding:30px 20px;background:rgba(64,82,100,0.92);color:#ffffff;margin-bottom:20px}.btn-download{background:rgba(24,42,60,0.92);color:rgba(124,142,160,0.92);padding:20px 50px;display:inline-block;-webkit-border-radius:5px;-moz-border-radius:5px;-o-border-radius:5px;-ms-border-radius:5px;border-radius:5px}.btn-download:hover{background:rgba(94,112,130,0.92)}.wrapper{max-width:1000px;margin:0 auto}.wrapper:before,.wrapper:after{content:'';display:table;clear:both}footer{margin-top:30px;background:rgba(24,42,60,0.92);color:rgba(124,142,160,0.92);padding:20px 0;text-align:left;font-size:0.9em}@keyframes anima{from{margin-top:-50px;-ms-filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=($opacity * 100))";filter:alpha(opacity=0);-moz-opacity:0;-khtml-opacity:0;opacity:0}to{margin:auto;-ms-filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=($opacity * 100))";filter:alpha(opacity=100);-moz-opacity:1;-khtml-opacity:1;opacity:1}}@-webkit-keyframes anima{from{margin-left:-20px;-ms-filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=($opacity * 100))";filter:alpha(opacity=0);-moz-opacity:0;-khtml-opacity:0;opacity:0}to{margin-left:10px;-ms-filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=($opacity * 100))";filter:alpha(opacity=100);-moz-opacity:1;-khtml-opacity:1;opacity:1}}@media screen and (max-width: 560px){.wrapper{padding:20px}}.pic{max-width:300px;max-height:200px;position:relative;overflow:hidden;margin:10px;display:inline-block;-webkit-animation:anima 2s;-moz-animation:anima 2s;-o-animation:anima 2s;-ms-animation:anima 2s;animation:anima 2s;-webkit-backface-visibility:hidden;-moz-backface-visibility:hidden;-o-backface-visibility:hidden;-ms-backface-visibility:hidden;backface-visibility:hidden}.pic-3d{-webkit-perspective:500;-moz-perspective:500;-o-perspective:500;-ms-perspective:500;perspective:500;-webkit-transform-style:preserve-3d;-moz-transform-style:preserve-3d;-o-transform-style:preserve-3d;-ms-transform-style:preserve-3d;transform-style:preserve-3d}.pic-caption{cursor:default;position:absolute;width:100%;height:100%;background:rgba(44,62,80,0.92);padding:10px;text-align:center;-ms-filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=($opacity * 100))";filter:alpha(opacity=0);-moz-opacity:0;-khtml-opacity:0;opacity:0}.pic-image{-webkit-transform:scale(1.1);-moz-transform:scale(1.1);-o-transform:scale(1.1);-ms-transform:scale(1.1);transform:scale(1.1)}.pic:hover .pic-image{-webkit-transform:scale(1);-moz-transform:scale(1);-o-transform:scale(1);-ms-transform:scale(1);transform:scale(1)}.pic-title{font-size:1.8em}a,a:hover,.pic .pic-image,.pic-caption,.pic:hover .pic-caption,.pic:hover img{-webkit-transition:all 0.5s ease;-moz-transition:all 0.5s ease;-o-transition:all 0.5s ease;-ms-transition:all 0.5s ease;transition:all 0.5s ease}.pic:hover .bottom-to-top,.pic:hover .top-to-bottom,.pic:hover .left-to-right,.pic:hover .right-to-left,.pic:hover .rotate-in,.pic:hover .rotate-out,.pic:hover .open-up,.pic:hover .open-down,.pic:hover .open-left,.pic:hover .open-right,.pic:hover .come-left,.pic:hover .come-right{-ms-filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=($opacity * 100))";filter:alpha(opacity=100);-moz-opacity:1;-khtml-opacity:1;opacity:1;-webkit-user-select:none;-moz-user-select:none;-o-user-select:none;-ms-user-select:none;user-select:none;-webkit-touch-callout:none;-moz-touch-callout:none;-o-touch-callout:none;-ms-touch-callout:none;touch-callout:none;-webkit-tap-highlight-color:transparent;-moz-tap-highlight-color:transparent;-o-tap-highlight-color:transparent;-ms-tap-highlight-color:transparent;tap-highlight-color:transparent}.bottom-to-top{top:50%;left:0}.pic:hover .bottom-to-top{top:0;left:0}.top-to-bottom{bottom:50%;left:0}.pic:hover .top-to-bottom{left:0;bottom:0}.left-to-right{top:0;right:50%}.pic:hover .left-to-right{right:0;top:0}.right-to-left{top:0;left:50%}.pic:hover .right-to-left{left:0;top:0}.rotate-in{-webkit-transform:rotate(90deg) scale(0.1);-moz-transform:rotate(90deg) scale(0.1);-o-transform:rotate(90deg) scale(0.1);-ms-transform:rotate(90deg) scale(0.1);transform:rotate(90deg) scale(0.1);top:0;left:0}.pic:hover .rotate-in{-webkit-transform:rotate(360deg) scale(1);-moz-transform:rotate(360deg) scale(1);-o-transform:rotate(360deg) scale(1);-ms-transform:rotate(360deg) scale(1);transform:rotate(360deg) scale(1)}.rotate-out{-webkit-transform:rotate(90deg) scale(3);-moz-transform:rotate(90deg) scale(3);-o-transform:rotate(90deg) scale(3);-ms-transform:rotate(90deg) scale(3);transform:rotate(90deg) scale(3);top:0;left:0}.pic:hover .rotate-out{-webkit-transform:rotate(360deg) scale(1);-moz-transform:rotate(360deg) scale(1);-o-transform:rotate(360deg) scale(1);-ms-transform:rotate(360deg) scale(1);transform:rotate(360deg) scale(1)}.open-down{-webkit-transform:rotateX(-180deg);-moz-transform:rotateX(-180deg);-o-transform:rotateX(-180deg);-ms-transform:rotateX(-180deg);transform:rotateX(-180deg);top:0;left:0}.pic:hover .open-down{-webkit-transform:rotateX(0);-moz-transform:rotateX(0);-o-transform:rotateX(0);-ms-transform:rotateX(0);transform:rotateX(0)}.open-up{-webkit-transform:rotateX(180deg);-moz-transform:rotateX(180deg);-o-transform:rotateX(180deg);-ms-transform:rotateX(180deg);transform:rotateX(180deg);top:0;left:0}.pic:hover .open-up{-webkit-transform:rotateX(0);-moz-transform:rotateX(0);-o-transform:rotateX(0);-ms-transform:rotateX(0);transform:rotateX(0)}.open-left{-webkit-transform:rotateY(180deg);-moz-transform:rotateY(180deg);-o-transform:rotateY(180deg);-ms-transform:rotateY(180deg);transform:rotateY(180deg);left:0;top:0}.pic:hover .open-left{-webkit-transform:rotateY(0deg);-moz-transform:rotateY(0deg);-o-transform:rotateY(0deg);-ms-transform:rotateY(0deg);transform:rotateY(0deg)}.open-right{-webkit-transform:rotateY(-180deg);-moz-transform:rotateY(-180deg);-o-transform:rotateY(-180deg);-ms-transform:rotateY(-180deg);transform:rotateY(-180deg);left:0;top:0}.pic:hover .open-right{-webkit-transform:rotateY(0deg);-moz-transform:rotateY(0deg);-o-transform:rotateY(0deg);-ms-transform:rotateY(0deg);transform:rotateY(0deg)}.come-left{-webkit-transform:rotateY(90deg) rotateX(90deg);-moz-transform:rotateY(90deg) rotateX(90deg);-o-transform:rotateY(90deg) rotateX(90deg);-ms-transform:rotateY(90deg) rotateX(90deg);transform:rotateY(90deg) rotateX(90deg);left:0;top:0}.pic:hover .come-left{-webkit-transform:rotateY(0) rotateX(0);-moz-transform:rotateY(0) rotateX(0);-o-transform:rotateY(0) rotateX(0);-ms-transform:rotateY(0) rotateX(0);transform:rotateY(0) rotateX(0)}.come-right{-webkit-transform:rotateY(-90deg) rotateX(-90deg);-moz-transform:rotateY(-90deg) rotateX(-90deg);-o-transform:rotateY(-90deg) rotateX(-90deg);-ms-transform:rotateY(-90deg) rotateX(-90deg);transform:rotateY(-90deg) rotateX(-90deg);left:0;top:0}.pic:hover .come-right{-webkit-transform:rotateY(0) rotateX(0);-moz-transform:rotateY(0) rotateX(0);-o-transform:rotateY(0) rotateX(0);-ms-transform:rotateY(0) rotateX(0);transform:rotateY(0) rotateX(0)}@media screen and (max-width: 560px){.pic{max-width:400px;max-height:300px;display:block;-webkit-animation:none;-moz-animation:none;-o-animation:none;-ms-animation:none;animation:none;margin:10px auto}}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <title>InContent - A content image hover effects.</title>
 <meta charset="utf-8" />
 
 <!-- Main CSS -->
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/sass-compiled.css" />
 
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 
 <!-- Viewport -->
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
 
 <style>
 
 </style>

</head>
<body>
 


 <section>
  <!--Effect: Bottom to Top -->
  <div class="pic"  id="first">
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/city-q-c-200-200-2.jpg" class="pic-image" alt="Pic"/>
      <span class="pic-caption bottom-to-top">
          <h1 class="pic-title">FIRST</h1>
          <p>LINK TO THE FIRST DIV</p>
      </span>
  </div>

  <!--Effect: Top to Bottom -->
  <div class="pic" id="second">
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/business-q-c-200-200-3.jpg" class="pic-image" alt="Pic"/>
      <span class="pic-caption top-to-bottom">
          <h1 class="pic-title">SECOND</h1>
          <p>LINK TO THE SECOND DIV</p>
      </span>
  </div>
  
  <div class="home-text">
   <h1>HOME</h1>
   Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
  </div>
  <div class="first-content">
   <h1>FIRST</h1>
   Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
  </div>
  <div class="second-content">
   <h1>SECOND</h1>
   Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
  </div>
  
 </section>
 <!-- End of effects -->


 <!-- TOUCH FRIENDLY IN MOBILE DEVICES -->
 <script>

 </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi, Please put your code here . when we don't have your code cant help you.

Comment: I guess you've accidently missed my link to the js.bin upload i've mentioned in my question.

Comment: The code must be placed in the question itself, not to some external site.

Comment: @Juhana it's perfectly fine to host your code on sites like https://jsfiddle.net/ and provide only a link. Actually it's much more helpful than an inline code.

Comment: @akoskm No, it isn't. The site doesn't even let you post a link to jsfiddle without any code in the question.

Comment: @Juhana but you agree that posting a complete, working example in form of a jsfiddle or jsbin is more helpful than just some code and figuring out what doesn't work simply by looking at it.

Comment: Yes, **in addition** to posting the code to the question. No-one is asking the OP to *remove* the jsbin link.

Comment: Alright i've implemented the code snippet into my stackoverflow question.